# Get all texts and items of open applications on Windows (UI Automation)

Tags: windows, automation, ui-automation

I need a source code to retrieve all Texts and Items (Menu Items, List Items,...) of all open applications... Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link to the [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation).

I know MS has their own framework built on top of such APIs.
Hope this helps.